# StreamReader very slow for big files

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am wanting to read in a file which in this case is 3mb
doing this takes around 50-60 seconds, which seems very slow. Does anyone know how to make this faster?

```
string text = null;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        text += (line);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(text.Length);
    }
}
```

I also need to use a background worker so I can report the percentage that has been loaded (for files around 500mb to 1gb)

Comment: Have you tried your test without concatenating to a `System.String`, i.e. commenting out the `text += (line);` line?

Comment: Maybe you don't want to read it per line but with a fixed buffer length.

Comment: @Christian.K I did that and it was instant. Now how would I go about getting the text?

Comment: See @RB's answer (use `StringBuilder` instead).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder to create your line - it's much more performant than string concatenation.

```
using System.Text;

//...

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        text.Append(line);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(text.Length);
    }
}

// ...
// Do something with the file you have read in.
Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
```

Comment: That will cause a NullReferenceException; looks like `text` is never initialized?

Comment: But `text` _is_ initialized... to `null` (Third nonempty line of the snippet).

Answer (score 4):

> StreamReader very slow for big files C#

NO, it is not. If you would have done your basic homework of running a profiler, you would see that the time you spend is NOT spent in the stream reader.

> text += (line);

This line is creating a new string. For this is has to allocate new memory. For a large file this is a SIGNIFICANT amount of garbage created. And the longer it gets, the more copy operations you do.

If that is what you use it for

> backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(text.Length);

it is also useless. You can also have an

> int textLength = 0

that you then set

> textLength += line.Length

without all the text manipulation.

You SHOULD have known that. Performance problem? NEVER assume, ALWAYS us a profiler - which would very promptly have shown you the issue. This is basic debugging.

Some background math, btw:

> (for files around 500mb to 1gb)

That means that once you load 500mb of data your code is making a 500mb (if the file was unicode) to 1gb (string double the size of an ascii file) copy operation PER LINE.

You may want to look up the memory speed of your computer. Depending on server etc. you may be limited to 50gb per second (high end X99 - the newer DDR 4 memories are faster, but workstations genererally have a lot less channels so are slower again) and a copy counts double (read and write). Which means that you really start running into "copying the string is overloading them memory bus" scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
```

Comment: Yes, but then there is no way to report progress while doing so (looks like that is important to the OP - then maybe not).

Comment: Also, if he's dealing with large files he might not want to read them all into memory at once (he does mention 1GB files in his question).